# How could I use scanf in a function?

Tags: c, scanf

```
void mscanf(char *format, ...)
{
  scanf(format);
}
int main()
{
  int n1, n2;
  mscanf("%d%d", &n1, &n2);
  printf("%d,%d\n", n1, n2);
  return 0;
}
```

what's wrong with this.?
How could I use scanf in a function just like this?
thanks.

Comment: How does it ever make sense to just pass one parameter to scanf, va_list or not?

Comment: @Lundin: It's a legal way to validate that the input is exactly what you expect. Which normally isn't very _useful_, but if you're, say, generating C code from a script, you could easily end up with a few trivial scans between more useful ones.

Comment: @abarnert Ah yeah that is true. However, I doubt that is what the OP was attempting here.

Comment: @Lundin: No, the OP clearly wanted to pass the arguments of `mscanf` to `scanf`, and didn't know how to write it, so… I'm guessing he just wrote that as a placeholder.

Comment: See: http://www.c-faq.com/varargs/vprintf.html and http://www.c-faq.com/varargs/handoff.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of your `scanf` you want [`vscanf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/vfscanf.html):

```
va_list args;
va_start(args, format);
vscanf(format, args);
va_end(args);
```

---

When you use functions with variable arguments list you sometimes stumble on the need to **pass those variable arguments**. So in your example you know what you want to do, you want to "pass the '...' to the scanf". That's exactly what the `vscanf`, `vprintf` etc functions are for: they accept the '...' in the form of a `va_list`.

Comment: +1. But you may want to actually explain what stdarg is for, and what the v* functions are for, so the OP and futures readers understand why this works instead of just using it as a magic invocation.

Comment: @vito_yu: `scanf` takes variable arguments. C doesn't provide any way to forward variable arguments from one function to another. But it does provide a way to read variable arguments into an `va_list`, and (at least with POSIX and/or C99) most variable-argument functions in the standard library have parallel versions that start with `v` and take a `va_list`.